# Find equation of a plane which contains pt A and the line l3

Tags: vectors

I need to find an equation of a plane, X, which has a line , l3, parrel to it. Also point A is on the plane and also on the line l3. 
The plane X is perpendicular to another plane Y.
Plane X meets plane Y at Point C

Pt A ( 2,-3,2)
Pt C (0,-2,1)

Line l3 (2,-3,2) + t(2,-1,1) 
Plane Y (2,-1,1) = 3

Comment: Could you provide some information on your attempts?

Comment: I usually cross multiply the 2 vectors together to get the normal but i dont have 3 points to be able to get the normal. Also the 2 points are on the line given so I don't have an idea how I am going to work it out

Comment: What confuses me : $Y$ is perpendicular to $X$, so $(2,-1,1)$ should be the second direction vector of $X$, but it coincides with the $(2,-1,1)$ of the line, so we do not get a plane this way. Please check whether $C$ or $Y$ differ from what you mentioned.

Comment: Plane X contains the line l3 on it. Line l3 happens to be the normal of plane Y

Comment: You might start by reading the solutions the the many similar problems listed in the “Related” column at right.